# kills an Android AsyncTask with a timeout

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, timeout, jsoup

So my problem is that i have a AsyncTask that scraps html from a page on a server so i used Jsoup as a library .
so the problem is that i want to set a timeout to cancel the Task if i don't receive any data from the page and display that there is a "communication error " on a toast

is there anyway to kill or stop the asynctask within it self and return a result on onPostExecute

```
{
private class getPageTitle extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        String title;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            connectServerProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginScreen.this);
            connectServerProgressDialog.setTitle("CheckingServer");
            connectServerProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            connectServerProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

            connectServerProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


            try {

                // Connect to the web site
                                Document document = Jsoup.connect(CONNECT_URL).get();

                            title = document.title();

                           } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null ;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            if(result!=null){

            switch (title) {
                case "0":
                    Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,"offline",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    connectServerProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    break;
                case "1":
                    connectServerProgressDialog.dismiss();
                     Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,"Connected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;

            }}else{
                Toast.makeText(LoginScreen.this,"Communication error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            }
        }}
```

Comment: I've never used soup however reading the documentation you can specify a connection timeout parameter.http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html

Answer (score 0):

I have a convention that I use for `AsyncTask` subclasses.

- Define an inner interface for the client to use.  This decouples the client class so that the `AsyncTask` can be re-used.  The interface is named in the form `blahblahListener`.
- The interface has two methods of the form `blahblahCompleted()` and `blahblahException()`.
- Accept a callback object (listener) that is an implementation of that interface.  This is either passed in the `AsyncTask` constructor or set with a `setListener()` method.
- Hold that listener reference in a `WeakReference` field so that if the listener goes away before the task completes, the listener can still be garbage-collected.
- Define a field to hold an `Exception`.  If an exception occurs in the background method, this field remembers the exception in order to report it to the client.
- In the `onPostExecute()` method, check if the Exception field is null.  If it is, call `blahblahCompleted()` with the result.  If it isn't, call `blahblahException()` with the exception.  Also check if the `WeakReference` is still valid.

For killing the task, you can have a timeout set on your connection.  Then when your connection times out, you will get an exception, which is remembered and reported.

So using that convention, your code would look like this:

```
public class WebPageTitleRemoteTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, String> {

    private WeakReference<WebPageTitleRetrievalListener> mListener;

    private Exception mException;

    public WebPageTitleRemoteTask(WebPageTitleRetrievalListener listener) {
        super();
        mListener = new WeakReference<WebPageTitleRetrievalListener>(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {

        String title = null;

        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(params[0]).get();
            title = document.title();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            mException = e;
        }

        return title;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        WebPageTitleRetrievalListener listener = mListener.get();
        if (listener != null) {
            if (mException == null) {
                listener.webPageTitleRetrieved(result);
            } else {
                listener.webPageTitleRetrievalException(mException);
            }
        }
    }

    public static interface WebPageTitleRetrievalListener {

        public void webPageTitleRetrieved(String title);

        public void webPageTitleRetrievalException(Exception e);
    }

}
```

And your client code would look something like this, with your `Activity` implementing that inner interface:

```
    .
    .
    .
    connectServerProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginScreen.this);
    connectServerProgressDialog.setTitle("CheckingServer");
    connectServerProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    connectServerProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);

    connectServerProgressDialog.show();

    new WebPageTitleRemoteTask(this).execute(url);
    .
    .
    .

@Override
public void webPageTitleRetrieved(String title) {

    if (isFinishing()) return;
    connectServerProgressDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(this, "title = " + title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void webPageTitleRetrievalException(Exception e) {

    if (isFinishing()) return;
    connectServerProgressDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

NOTE: Because the listener is held in a `WeakReference`, you can't use an anonymous inner class for the listener, because the reference will go away almost immediately and be eligible for garbage collection.

I use this convention consistently, and the extra boilerplate code in the `AsyncTask` subclass makes it a lot cleaner to use in the client class.